# How do I handle built-in storage AND an external SD card?

Tags: android, storage, sd-card

Okay, so I've done as much research as I can to try and figure out if I'm doing anything wrong, but nothing on Google or the Android tutorials could really answer me in my scenario.

**The Scenario:**

Let's say I have an Android device that comes with 16GB of built-in storage. Let's also assume that the device has a 32GB SD scard. Basically, the device has a  total 48GB of storage space. My app needs to scan every *user-accessible* location on the device. In other words, I need to be able to access and read every place that a regular user (non-root) can read and write to.

**What I'm doing right now:**

I'm using the recommended `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which points me to `/mnt/sdcard`.

**The Question:**

Is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` going to give me access to every user-accessible storage on the device? I'm confused because there can be 16GB of built-in storage and 32GB of SD card storage, but how does Android handle the two separate locations? Does it simply combine the two into a singular `/mnt/sdcard` or am I only able to access one of the two storage directories with my line of code?

Sorry if this sounds like a noob question, but coming from an iPhone background where the only storage available is internal storage, I'm really stumped by Android's method of handling this situation. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory(). Quoting from docs  Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() going to give me access to every user-accessible storage on the device?

No. It points you to [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

> how does Android handle the two separate locations?

Android itself mostly only cares about the one spot designated as external storage. Anything above and beyond that is device-specific and is up to the manufacturer (or, possibly, ROM mod maintainer).

This is why you do not see anything in the current Android SDK for accessing multiple volumes that all might be considered "external storage".

> Does it simply combine the two into a singular /mnt/sdcard

No.

> or am I only able to access one of the two storage directories with my line of code?

Yes.

**UPDATE**: I wrote [a series of blog posts](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) to try to help developers make sense of the Android storage situation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the super quick reply! I'm basically making a music player so I need to be able to access music files that the user transferred to his/her device. Let's say that the user has a few files on his/her built-in storage and a few files on their physical SD card. How do I access both of those locations? From what it sounds like in your post, I'm only targetting one of these two locations when I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). Thanks again!

Comment: @user1666541: "How do I access both of those locations?" -- an ordinary music player shouldn't be caring about *any* of those locations. An ordinary music player should be finding its music through the `MediaStore`. Many device manufacturers augment the `MediaStore` to index all user-facing storage locations, not just the official external storage. Plus, it saves you from having to scan all that stuff yourself. If you don't want to use `MediaStore`, you have no reliable options for accessing user-facing stores other than the device's official external storage.

Comment: That's interesting. I was using `MediaStore` until a couple of weeks ago, but I switched over to my own custom scanner because I needed some functionality that `MediaStore` doesn't provide. I still don't understand this though: If the user can access two separate locations for his/her SD card and built-in storage, shouldn't I be able to access them too? Thanks again for all your help so far.

Comment: @user1666541: "I needed some functionality that MediaStore doesn't provide" -- you have transcended "an ordinary music player" then and are now on a higher plane of existence. :-) "shouldn't I be able to access them too?" -- well, if you ask anyone outside of Mountain View, CA, the answer is "yes". This has been a common complaint for a couple of years now. Android 4.3 still hasn't added anything for this, so now we're hoping that perhaps Android 5.0 will. There are recipes for trying to figure out paths via Linux files/commands, but they are unreliable IMHO and should be avoided by newcomers.

Comment: "You have transcended an ordinary music player then and are now on a higher plane of existence". I'll take that as a compliment haha. :) Thanks! MediaStore wouldn't let me pick which folders to scan for music and that's a killer feature I want to implement into my app. It sucks that Android doesn't have a robust way to access both internal and microSD storage. Thanks for all your help though! I'll look into the hackish ways that other people are using for now. I've been at Android for about a year so I should be fine tinkering around haha. That's where the fun's at!

Comment: @user1666541: As with iOS (as I understand it), Android tries to get users away from thinking of files, which is one of the reasons why path information is not in `MediaStore`. And my apologies, but I assumed from the closing paragraph of your question that you were a newcomer to Android.